# Several singletons: one for each task

Tags: c++, multithreading, singleton, task, ssl

I have a C++ multi-threaded application which run tasks in separate threads. Each task have an object which handles and stores it's output.  Each task create different business logic objects and probably another threads or threadpools.

What I want to do is somehow provide an easy way for any of business logic objects which are run by task to access each task's output without manually passing "output" object to each business logic object.

What i see is to create output singleton factory and store task_id in TLS. But the problem is when business logic create a new thread or thread pool and those thread would not have task_id in TLS. In this way i would need to have an access to parent's thread TLS.

The other way is to simply grab all output since task's start. There would be output from different task in that time, but at least, better than nothing...

I'm looking for any suggestions or ideas of clean and pretty way of solving my problem. Thanks.

**upd:** yeah, it is not singletone, I agree. I just want to be able to access this object like this:

```
output << "message";
```

And that's it. No worry of passing pointers to output object between business logic classes. I need to have a global output object per task.

Comment: Multithreading + Singletons = Death + Destruction (usually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an application point of view, they are not singletons, so why treating the objects like singletons?

I would make a new instance of the output storer and pass the (smart?) pointer to the new thread.  The main function may put the pointer in the TLS, thus making the instance global per thread (I don't think that this is a wise design deision, but it is asked).  When making a new (sub-?)thread, the pointer can again be passed.  So according to me, no singletons or factories are needed.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about storing pointer in the TLS in newly created thread. But i don't really like having special threading functions for tasks.

Comment: How are you planning on having a "singleton per thread" without TLS?  Anyway, I would go for passing references via constructors and not be bothered with singletons, but that is my approach.

Comment: BTW: with the TLS approach, you would have `output() << "message";` instead of `output << "message";`

Comment: Yeah, I also think that TLS approach may bring a lot of problems and bugs. So, passing references is probably the only way. Thanks anyway.

BTW: with TLS approach I would have used macroses and had as simple usage as I want :)

Comment: Actually, I kind of like the `output()` way, but best of luck with whatever approach you will be using.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have multiple class instances (each not necessarily the same class) all be able to access a common data pool that needs to be thread safe. I can think of a few ways to do this. The first idea is to have this data pool in a class that each of the other classes contain. This data pool will actually store it's data in a static member, so that way there is only one instance of the data even though there will be more than one instance of the data pool class. The class will then have accessor methods which access this static data pool (so that it is transparent). To make it thread safe you would then require the access to go through a mutex or something like that.

Comment: No. There is common data pool only inside each task. But globally there would be N output objects and N tasks.

Comment: So, is the output common across all tasks? I don't really understand what you mean by "access each task's output" if not in that context. If so, then my answer will work, and you will consider the common output as the "data pool". If not, then I would assume that each business logic would have some way of understanding the portions of output that it wants, and so a commonality can still be drawn from that. I hope that helps. I would be able to help more if I understood a bit better what the output was and what the business logic of some of the tasks were trying to do.